# SVG Fill Animation in Safari

Tags: css, animation, svg, fill, keyframe

I am trying to use Keyframe animation fill property of a svg element. This works perfectly fine in every browser except for Desktop Safari. I searched and tried a lot of workarounds like starting the animation at 1% instead of 0% but nothing worked. Other properties like opacity are animated perfectly in Safari, it seems like it is just the fill property that does not work.

If possible,I would like to avoid having to use Javascript for such a simple animation. Does anybody have a good workaround?

**HTML Code:**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="65.056px" viewBox="0 0 150 65.056" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 65.056;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path .../>
</svg>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
svg {
  -webkit-animation: logo-color 20s infinite linear;
  animation: logo-color 20s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes logo-color {
  0% {
    fill: red;
  }
  50% {
    fill: green;
  }
  100% {
    fill: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: For anybody who stumbles upon this post with the same problem: i rewrote my animation, now using filter() instad of fill. Since my logo is only one color, this works perfectly for me in every browser.

Comment: You could use the animate element for cross browser.